# In John 15:15 how is a friend different from a servant?

Tags: john, matthew, prophecy, amos

> [Jhn 15:15 NIV] (15) I no longer call you servants, because a servant does not know his master's business. Instead, I have called you friends, for everything that I learned from my Father I have made known to you.

How is that different from God's servants, the prophets?

> [Amo 3:7 ASV] (7) Surely the Lord Jehovah will do nothing, except he reveal his secret unto his servants the prophets.

Probably related:

> [Mat 13:17 DBY] (17) for verily I say unto you, that many prophets and righteous men have desired to see the things which ye behold and did not see them, and to hear the things which ye hear and did not hear them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is there in the verse itself:

> **John 15:15 (DRB)** I will not now call you servants: **for the servant knoweth not what his lord doth. But I have called you friends: because all things whatsoever I have heard of my Father, I have made known to you.**

One intimates his plans and secrets to friends, but not to servants; Christ, by extension, calls us friends because He does not merely call us to service, but to friendship, and sonship of God.

Such is never intended to make them mutually exclusive; one could add here, "mere" to "servants," inasmuch as a servant can become friends while still serving. Jesus is only speaking generally of two quite different roles and relationships; for Christians, serving is a joy, rather than labor. The Apostles were the "servants" of Christ (Romans 1:1; James 1:1; 2 Peter 1:1; Jude 1:1), as are Christians (Revelation 1:1, etc.).

Comment: How is that different from the status of the prophets who are called servants. Don't they know as do the friends? [Amo 3:7 ASV] (7) Surely the Lord Jehovah will do nothing, except he reveal his secret unto his servants the prophets.

Comment: They do. God doesn't say, 'You are servants *but not* my friends.' Abraham was called both servant and friend, for example (Genesis 26:24; James 2:23; 2 Chronicles 20:7). In Isaiah 48:1, they are even in parallel! Jesus is obviously just speaking about servants verses friends as in the normative relationship differences. God's servants are like friends to Him, as are, by extension, Jesus'.

Comment: Well, it seems to me he does:  "I will not now call you servants...".

Comment: @Sola Gratia - I think your answer is excellent +1.  The fact that we are friends of the almighty and that Christ is our brother does not exclude us also being servants of God to do his bidding.

Comment: @Ruminator "I will not now call you servants" can be interpreted as meaning, "merely servants," as merely such.

Comment: @Sola Gratia "In Isaiah 48:1, they are even in parallel! " Found it in 41:8-9.